# how to have Arabic .txt file with 7-bit encoding

Tags: character-encoding

I need a method to save a .txt file written with Arabic letters but its size(bytes) as if its written with English letters, by changing encoding from 8-bit(e.g. UTF-8) to 7-bit(e.g. GSM 7). notice that English letters .txt file is smaller in size than arabic for the same number of letters coz English one is encoded by using ASCii standard (7-bit) while Arabic by UTF-8(8-bit) .
this is important in telecommunication industry when one SMS should not exceed 140 byte.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38#Urdu_language_(Arabic_and_basic_Latin_scripts) BTW there is a similar question in last 24h -- Note: I think you have some misconception about encoding, data size, etc. ASCII is one encoding (but not used on SMS), and Arabic has many encoding. UTF-8 is just a general encoding (which permit also to properly encode English [ASCII is just a subset of most used character for English in old telecomunication world]). SMS uses UCS-2/UTF-16 and not UTF-8

Comment: U are Right, but I upload txt files daily to use it in USSD not SMS, for sms it's still 140 byte/page regardless encoding. I am not looking for concepts but the way to do it. For misconception you conclude,  I categorized things to 7-bit & 8-bit to clarify the point instead of current inconvenient standard definition.

Comment: SMS has also some "off-band" communication, which tell how to interpret the encoding. Now by default you may see UCS2/UTF16. I think you should check on the library which inject to the system about such things. As being out-of-band data, this cannot be expressed in any txt file.

Answer (score 0):

The standard solution is probably to use iso-8859-6, but that will give you exactly 8 bits for every character. If you really want to use only 7 bits for each character you will probably have to invent your own non-standard solution.

Comment: I want to use  GSM 03.38 or similar but I have no tools ot method.

Comment: @zaidabdullah: Wikipedia has a 1-1 correspondence between character and encoded value. Just doesn't expect your `.txt` file to be 7-bit, or etc. This must be done at transport level (of just you should shift a bit to every 8. But that would not be a ".txt" file

Comment: I will double check and back